# getColorStateList has been deprecated

Tags: android, android-theme

I'm having a problem here. I've just updated from sdk 22 to 23, and the previous version of "getColorStateList()" has been deprecated.

My code was like this

```
seekBar.setProgressTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.bar_green));
valorslide.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.text_green));
```

The older "getColorStateList" was

```
getColorStateList(int id)
```

And new one is

```
getColorStateList(int id, Resources.Theme theme)
```

How do I use the Theme variable? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The Theme object is the theme that is used to style the color state list. If you aren't using any special theming with individual resources, you can either pass `null` or the current theme as follows:

```
TextView valorslide; // initialize
SeekBar seekBar; // initialize
Context context = this;
Resources resources = context.getResources();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    seekBar.setProgressTintList(resources.getColorStateList(R.color.bar_green, context.getTheme()));
    valorslide.setTextColor(resources.getColorStateList(R.color.text_green, context.getTheme()));
} else {
    seekBar.setProgressTintList(resources.getColorStateList(R.color.bar_green));
    valorslide.setTextColor(resources.getColorStateList(R.color.text_green));
}
```

If you don't don't care about the theme, you can just pass null:

```
getColorStateList(R.color.text_green, null)
```

[See the documentation for more explanation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColorStateList(int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme)) Note, you only need to use the new version on API 23 (Android Marshmallow) and above.

Comment: Or, just stick with the deprecated version, as unless your `minSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, you will need to use the deprecated version on older devices anyway.

Comment: @CommonsWare I should have pointed that out, updated to reflect that information. Thanks.

Comment: I tried null before and it crashed. I tried both things now (null and getTheme()), and it still crashes

`14635-14635/golden.imper.csystemhelper E/MessageQueue-JNI﹕ java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getColorStateList(ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/content/res/Co‌​lorStateList; in class Landroid/content/res/Resources; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.content.res.Resources' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)`

Comment: @fkchaud you need to check the API version before using that method on below API 23 as I have in my updated answer, because it will throw that error if you try to use the updated method on pre-Android M versions. Also, make sure you are compiling against API 23.

Comment: @anthonycr that's it, I was testing it in API 21 and that's why it crashed. It works now. Thanks both!

Comment: ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_color)

Answer (score 52):

While anthonycr's answer works, it is a lot more compact to just write

```
ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.haml_indigo_blue);
```

Comment: This works cool! Is there anything like that but for seekbar methods? I have compatibility issues (solved with anthony's answer) with `seekBar.setProgressTintList()`
(I don't really need this, it's for knowledge)

Comment: how can make `ColorStateList` from a custom color and not from resource color?

Answer (score 3):

Exactly if you are using them , you will lose all styles. For an older version you should create `ColorStateList` dynamically, This is main chance to keep your styles.

this works for all versions

```
layout.setColorStateList(buildColorStateList(this,
   R.attr.colorPrimaryDark, R.attr.colorPrimary)
);


public ColorStateList buildColorStateList(Context context, @AttrRes int pressedColorAttr, @AttrRes int defaultColorAttr){
    int pressedColor = getColorByAttr(context, pressedColorAttr);
    int defaultColor = getColorByAttr(context, defaultColorAttr);

    return new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed},
                    new int[]{} // this should be empty to make default color as we want
            }, new int[]{
            pressedColor,
            defaultColor
    }
    );
}

@ColorInt
public static int getColorByAttr(Context context, @AttrRes int attrColor){

    if (context == null || context.getTheme() == null)
        return -1;

    Resources.Theme theme = context.getTheme();
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();

    theme.resolveAttribute(attrColor, typedValue,true);

    return typedValue.data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's also a newer approach:

```
AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(context, R.color.bar_green)
```

This keeps a weak reference to a cache of ColorStateList's that it has inflated and if it fails to load one, it falls back to `ContextCompat.getColorStateList`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ContextCompat.getColor(), which is part of the Support V4 Library (so it will work for all the previous API).

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_color)
```