# How to solve the Navigation View resource issue in Android Oreo?

Tags: android, android-navigationview, android-8.0-oreo

In Android Oreo device, Navigation View always showing below mentioned issue.

W/Resources: ColorStateList android:color/text_color_primary has unresolved theme attributes! Consider using Resources.getColorStateList(int, Theme) or Context.getColorStateList(int).
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException
                                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.getColorStateList(Resources.java:990)
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.createDefaultColorStateList(NavigationView.java:416)
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:144)
                                                                                  at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.(NavigationView.java:96)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                  at info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71)

how can i resolve this?

Comment: I think you are using some deprecated methods. Because Logcat suggest you should update them check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359832/getcolorstatelist-has-been-deprecated

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Xenolino. Its showing error like this android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) in the onCreate() method itself.

Comment: Show me  line `71` in your `MainActivity` ? What is the code in that line?

Comment: at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                at info.androidhive.navigationdrawer.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71)

Comment: In need the code itself not the logs. at line 71 that is where the error lies! what is the code? Open MainActivity.java and scroll to line 71 copy and paste it here!

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); line no 71 is setcontentview