# GetColorStateList and Forms.Context are obsolete in my Forms Android project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am getting a couple of messages now with my Forms Android project:

```
colors = Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.icon_tab);
```

> Warning CS0618: 'Resources.GetColorStateList(int)' is obsolete:
>   'deprecated' (CS0618)

```
ReadWriteStream(Forms.Context.Assets.Open(sqliteFilename), writeStream);
```

> 'Forms.Context' is obsolete: 'Context is obsolete as of version
>   2.5. Please use a local context instead.' (CS0618)

Does anyone have an idea as to how I can resolve these problems?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417015/xamarin-forms-2-5-0-and-context

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359832/getcolorstatelist-has-been-deprecated

Comment: One question per post please....